# Can I format the text inside a list in Python?

Tags: python, list, formatting

I have a list of 50 values that looks like this:

```
['xxxxxx\n', 'xxxxxx\n', 'xxxxxx\n', 'xxxxxx\n', 'xxxxxx   \n', 'xxxxxx\n',
 '    xxxxxx   \n', 'xxxxxx   \n', 'xxxxxx\n', ...]
```

I would like to print the list as a list, but format the text inside of the list. I would like to strip the whitespace before and after the word (which is replaced with xxxxxx for this example), as well as use the `.title()` function.

I've tried doing it, but I get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'strip'
```

I understand that error, but I'm wondering if there's any other way to format the text inside of a list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a list of the properly formatted string using

```
[s.strip().title() for s in my_list]
```

and do with that list whatever you want (including printing).

Comment: Further reading: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that strings are immutable, you have to create a new string and replace the old one inside the list. An easy way would be:

```
a = ['xxxxxx\n',  ' xxxxxx \n', 'xxxxxx \n', 'xxxxxx\n', ...]
a = [x.strip().title() for x in a]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
my_list=['xxxxxx\n', 'xxxxxx\n', 'xxxxxx\n', 'xxxxxx\n', 'xxxxxx   \n', 'xxxxxx\n', '    xxxxxx   \n', 'xxxxxx   \n', 'xxxxxx\n']

def format_string_from_list(_str):
    return _str.strip().title()

my_new_list=[format_string_from_list(_str) for _str in my_list]
print my_new_list

>>> ['Xxxxxx', 'Xxxxxx', 'Xxxxxx', 'Xxxxxx', 'Xxxxxx', 'Xxxxxx', 'Xxxxxx', 'Xxxxxx', 'Xxxxxx']
```

Comment: If you need to write an external function anyway (I really don't think you do in this case though) you might as well use `map(format_string_from_list, my_list)`. I think Sven's answer is much easier to read though

Answer (score 0):

My little mapped solution:

`my_list = ['xxxxxx\n', 'xxxxxx\n', 'xxxxxx\n', 'xxxxxx\n', 'xxxxxx   \n']` # shorted for brevity
`map(str.title, (map(str.strip, my_list)))`